# How to log-out android application when it is not using

Tags: android, logout, session-timeout

I am developing an `Android` application in which I can login with a particular userid and password. I want my application to be able to automatically log the user out when the application state is idle for 5 minutes.

How can I achieve this in `Android`.

Comment: did you mean session management ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`

Basic idea is, you override `onPause()` set an alarm in it for 5 minutes, and when that alarm returns, "log-out" the user. If the user returns you can cancel that alarm (override `onResume()`

Here is a good [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)  explaining usage of `AlarmManager` with code for cancelling and scheduling new alarms as well as handling the callbacks.

If you want to do it simpler, you can keep track of a static timestamp variable. Update this variable in your `onPause()`, then when the user returns (`onResume()`) check the time of this variable, see if 5 minutes has passed, if it has redirect user back to login

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of the idle state, you can start a `Service` when your activity is paused, where a `Timer` will run for 5 minutes before logging out the user and stopping the service. In each `Activitiy` you stop the timer in `onResume()` and start it again in `onPause()`. You can implement this behavior easily with a common base `Activity`. This will log out the user 5 minutes after he exited the last `Activity` in you application.